# Python CSV want array [x,y] as one of the datapoints but outputs "[x,y]" when CSV file is written

Tags: python, csv

My initial file has latitude and longitude and I'm trying to add a column position that keeps the latitude and longitude in an array [x , y]. My code below gives me a csv file where position stores the string "[x,y]" instead of the array [x,y]. How can I fix this?

```
fieldnames = ["position","latitude","longitude"]

with open("file1.csv", "rb") as csvinput:
    with open('file2.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
         csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, fieldnames, delimiter=',')
         csvwriter.writeheader()
         for row in csv.DictReader(csvinput):
                 row['position'] = [float(row["latitude"]),float(row["longitude"])]
                 csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: It is normal that CSV files have quotes around the values.

Comment: how do you want to store "the array [x,y]" in csv file if not as a string representation ?

Answer (score 1):

As you will see in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), all that is stored in a CSV file is in text form, so you need to write all the code to transform your data to strings and the other way around.

In this specific case, note also that the data you're trying to add already contains a comma. Hence, the data is quoted to prevent that comma from being interpreted as a separator for another column.

Comment: Thanks! i know why it does that now.